# Getting type of implementing class Scala

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

How to get type or ClassSymbol of implementing class. This always will give me class Model. I even tried to use generics, but typeOf[T] the compiler did not like and it was ugly anyways. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

abstract class Model {
  def className = typeOf[this.type].typeSymbol.asClass
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to get the `ClassSymbol`:

```
abstract class Model {      
    def classSymbol: ClassSymbol = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).classSymbol(getClass)
}
```

Comment: Perfect thanks! I can't upvote you because I have no reputation :(